# NoSuchMethodError error with Retrofit GET request

Tags: java, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am supposed to simply send a *get*-request to an endpoint and retrieve the data, and had success with *post*-request version of this code. However, it doesn't seem to work for GET. I have a simple model which is like this

```
public class Brand {
private String id;
private String name;

public Brand(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}}
```

And my repository

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.http.*;
import java.util.List;

public interface Service {

    @Headers({ "Accept: application/json" })
    @GET("/brands")
    Call<List<Brand>> getBrandList();

    @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
    @POST("/login/email")
    Call<ResponseBody> login(@Body LoginInfo loginInfo);

}
```

And finally this is where I try to run

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class BrandRepoImp {

    private static final String apiUrl = "http://example.com/grc/main/";

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        BrandRepoImp app=new BrandRepoImp();
        app.getBrandList();
    }
    public void getBrandList() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())                                         
                                .build();

        Service resource = retrofit.create(Service.class);
        Call<List<Brand>> brands = resource.getBrandList();
        System.out.println(brands.execute().body());
    }
}
```

It returns this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okio.BufferedSource.rangeEquals(JLokio/ByteString;)Z
>           at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:431)
>           at okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader.read(ResponseBody.java:249)
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1295)
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1333)
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
>           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
>           at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
>           at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
>           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
>           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
>           at com.retrofitexample.demo.login.BrandRepoImp.getBrandList(BrandRepoImp.java:27)
>           at com.retrofitexample.demo.login.BrandRepoImp.main(BrandRepoImp.java:17)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What version of Retrofit is this?

Comment: It's Retrofit 2

Comment: could you be more specific? Are you running on the latest version of their library to eliminate all the known and fixed defects?

Comment: My pom file says it's 2.3.0,which is the latest I believe

Comment: Are you sure your pom/grade-file includes the correct version on runtime? It seems like you somehow might be referencing two different versions.
Indicated by 
`...okio.BufferedSource.rangeEquals(JLokio/ByteString;)Z..`

Comment: Could it be the `Headers` you are passing should be a string type and not an object {}?

Comment: Everything retrofit related in my pom is 2.3.0,except http interceptor which I didn't use. I get the same error without that get header.(Login works fine)